# What are the limitations of PiZero GPIO?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero

PiZero does not seem to have conventional GPIO pins. How to use GPIO?

Comment: They are the exact same as the Pi 2.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please try to be more specific with your question. The Pi Zero has the same GPIO header pinout as the Pi 2 (as Patrick already mentioned) and there are quite a few questions&answers around here on *how to use them*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Patrick pointed out they have identical functionality to the Pi 2. The only difference is that the headers are not populated. This does have a few advantages, it allows you to choose the header style, in addition to the male headers which have come on all previous Pi's,

[image: male headers]

you can choose to use a right angle headers

[image: right angle headers]

which allow a a vertical mounting of the Pi (similar to a daughterboard or PCI card in your computer);

[image]

or female headers.

[image: female headers]

which allows mounting it directly to a [Pi Cobbler](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2028?gclid=CjwKEAiAzuK0BRCW4tiLpJT-8TISJADV8cw9sLkIE8HH-oqjs-LFdd9ZG-VXEsi0M6301pXIwl9PMxoCN5Hw_wcB)

[image: Pi and Pi cobbler]

The  decision not to populate the headers means that you do need to solder them yourself, but has the benefit of more flexibility in mounting and and connecting wires to the GPIO pins.

I replaced a (first Gen) Pi B with a Pi zero, because it made fitting the whole project into an enclosure much easier.

Images form adafruit.com [Introducing the Raspberry Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-zero/gpio-header-options)